# Nombre de mi App en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest

resulta que tengo una app que he realizado a la cual le cambie el nombre por : **mi_app** en el manifiesto de android, la app funciona bien e instala el icono con el nombre que yo le he dado("mi_app").
**El problema** que tengo es que  cuando preciono el botón para ver las aplicaciones que he usado recientemente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra que mi aplicacion tiene otro nombre(como muestro en la imagen):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque pasa esto? que tengo que hacer para cambiar ese texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede por que no has cambiado el `title` de tu `MaterialApp` que de seguro envuelve a tu clase principal en el **main.dart**. 
Aquí te pongo un ejemplo:

```
MaterialApp(      
      title: 'Flutter Tutorials',  //  AQUÍ DEBES CAMBIAR EL TEXTO Y TAMBIEN EL COLOR DE TU BARRA SI LO DESEAS
      theme: ThemeData(        
        accentColor: Colors.red[900],
        primaryColor: Colors.red[900],       
      ),
      home: Mi_clase(),
    );
```

Comment: Gracias! no se me habia pasado que pudiera ser eso :D